# Define a function $f(x)$ that gives the height of the stack of cups

Tags: functions

There are 5 cups in the stack. The height of first cup is $12.7$, then you stack second cup onto the first one and measure it and get $14.2$, do the same with the third cup and get $15.7$, do the same with the fourth cup $17.2$, do the same with the fifth cup and get $18.7$.

Give a function $f(x)$ that gives the height of the stack of the cups where $x$ is the number of cups in the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that the difference between the first height and the second height is $14.2 - 12.7 = 1.5$ this pattern continues between all successive heights.

Therefore we want this function $f$ to have height $12.7$ at $x = 1$ and height increased by $1.5$ for each successive cup added.

This is simply $f(x) = 12.7 + 1.5(x-1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the help.but it doesn't add up if you only have 1 cup in the stack. It does work for if your adding more cups to the original stack. Thanks again

Comment: Oh oops you're correct it should be initially $+ 12.7$, I've edited.

Comment: That does work thank you so much with helping me work out the problem

Comment: No problem, if you like my answer feel free to hit the check mark and upvote my answer.